# Should there be a tags for subjects that are considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close, close-reasons, scope

Looking at this question on SOLID: [Interface synonymous with abstract class with no implantations w.r.t. SOLID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215641/interface-synonymous-with-abstract-class-with-no-implantations-w-r-t-solid)

Downvoting and close voting implied that it's not quite right for here, however, we do have the tag [solid-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solid-principles).

Should there be a tag for subjects that are considered off topic?

Comment: It's not closed and it doesn't even have a negative score.

Comment: Not to mention that the tag includes quesitons that are highly upvoted like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399027/single-responsibility-principle-vs-anemic-domain-model-anti-pattern and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246068/how-do-you-define-a-single-responsibility

Comment: What good would that do? We only want relevant tags and keep fighting to keep it that way. Adding off-topic tags would be counter productive

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is did, it's been upvoted to zero now,  3 close votes though.

Comment: @juergend That's my point.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question and its title originally read:

> Is an interface the same as an abstract class with no implantations in .NET?

Even though you mention some SOLID principles the question is quite straightforward and the answer can be already found on Stack Overflow. This is the reason I have voted to close your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Now, that you **have changed the meaning of your question** that may not be a valid reason any longer...well, I don't have time to go back to every single question I cast a vote on and decide whether it's still valid or not - if it wasn't it will expire in a week or so...

The [solid-principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solid-principles) tag is not classified as an off-topic tag. [There currently are 255 questions which include it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solid-principles) and it doesn't seem like they're all off-topic.

> Should there be a tag for subjects that are considered off topic?

Definitely not. Don't generalize questions based on the tags they include. Each and every single question is specific and should be judged independently of any other related questions ( unless it's  a duplicate ).